# dt dd backgrounds alignement

Tags: html, css, styles

I want to render

```
<dl>
    <dt>word</dt><dd>meaning (long text with many lines)</dd>
    <dt>word</dt><dd>meaning (long text with many lines)</dd>
</dl>
```

with 2 different background colors for dt and dd

```
dt {
 float:left;
 width:10%;
 background:green;
}
dd {
 float:left;
 width:90%;
 background:transparent;
}
```

As my dt content text is very short, dt content appears in only 1 line.
As my dd content text is very long, dd content appears in many lines.

How can I render the 2 backgrounds with the same number of line (like with table) ?

Thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/5yVwN/

Comment: Can you make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use float, get rid of that, instead use only one dt and one dd for one dl, and set display to table cell for both.

Like so http://jsfiddle.net/5yVwN/